# $scope will be called before $http request in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Whenever program runs it first call the `$scope` method and hence I cannot get any data which will load Dbdata from `$http` method.

```
var fileData = $http.get("JS/filesystemsdata.json").success(function (data) {
    $scope.DbData = data;
    $scope.isDBLoaded = true;
}).error(function (status) {
    alert(status);
    $scope.isDBLoaded = false;
});

var afterdata = $scope.getChilds("Common Files", "c,Program Files");
console.log(afterdata);
```

Comment: Why dont you access `$scope.DbData` in your success promise?

Comment: $scope.getChilds() is called first and then $http is called due to which I am not getting required data.

Comment: Yea, we see that. This does not make any sense at all. Your data recived async. from your HTTP-Service is stored in `$scope.DbData`. So what you are trying to achieve while calling this unknown function `$scope.getChilds()` ? If you want `$scope.getChilds()` executed after the request was successful just put it inside your `success` function.

Comment: yaa got it... thanks...

Comment: Glad to help, added it as an answer.

Comment: Why the hell Java tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your function you like to execute into your `success` promise like:

```
var fileData = $http.get("JS/filesystemsdata.json").success(function (data) {
  $scope.DbData = data;
  $scope.isDBLoaded = true;
  var afterdata = $scope.getChilds("Common Files", "c,Program Files");
}).error(function (status) {
alert(status);
  $scope.isDBLoaded = false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

Contrary to your assumption stated in the question title, functions from your code will be called in a specified order:

- `$http.get`
- `$scope.getChilds`

However, the *success* and *error* callbacks for `$http.get` are **asynchronous**. That means that these functions will be called when the `$http.get` data is ready. I.e. this can take 1 millisecond or this can also take a whole minute (for example) – the *success / error* callbacks will be called when needed without stopping your main thread.

### Solution

So the solution is to put the `$scope.getChilds` part in the *success* callback.
I suggest you to learn more about callbacks and [promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) to have a better understanding.

### Side Note

Accroding to the AngularJS [$http docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.10/docs/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice), `success` and `error` methods are deprecated, and you should use `then` instead:

> The `$http` legacy promise methods `success` and `error` have been
>   deprecated and will be removed in v1.6.0. Use the standard `then` method
>   instead

Answer (score 0):

if you want second thing execute after first thing then you can use **$promise** or **then** function(then is a combination of success and error and then is the new thing)

```
 var fileData = $http.get("JS/filesystemsdata.json").then(function(data){
    $scope.DbData = data;
    $scope.isDBLoaded = true;
    var afterdata = $scope.getChilds("Common Files", "c,Program Files");
    console.log(afterdata);
}, function(status){
    alert(status);
    $scope.isDBLoaded = false;
});
```

for then

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

for $q

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q